# Will it be odd to #define inside a C++ function?

Tags: c++, coding-style, c-preprocessor

My little C++ function needs to calculate a simple timeout value.

```
CalcTimeout(const mystruct st)
{
    return (st.x + 100) * st.y + 200;
}
```

The numbers 100 and 200 would be confusing to read the code later so I would like to use #define for them. But these defines are only going to be needed for this function only, can I define them inside the function? The advantages this way are:

- It is very local values and nobody else needs to know about it
- Being closer to where it is used, the intent is clear, it has no other use, they are like local variables (except that they are not)

The disadvantage can be it is rather crude way to define something like local variable/const but it is obviously not local.

Other than that would this be odd to #define inside a C++ function? Most of the time we use #defines at the top of the file. Is using const variables better in any way in replacing a fixed local hard coded value like this?

The objective really is make code more readable/understandable.

Comment: Quite odd. And "nobody else knows about it" is not quite true, the preprocessor has no notion of scope. You'd be better off defining it before the function body, then `undef`ing after it.

Comment: Or just use the better alternative, since C++ and not C: const variable.

Comment: You _can_ do it, and you can `#undef` them when you are through with them.  But Mike Seymour's answer is a much better solution.

Comment: I'm not so sure a downvote is warranted. What's the rationale?

Comment: Does those two constants only make sense within a single function?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas yes, it will never be needed outside the function or any other place. Mike Seymour ans is convincing though.

Comment: @zadane: The question is not whether you are using them anywhere else, but whether they have a meaning outside of the function. There might be a single function that deals with the minimum margins of a printer in the driver, but the minimum margin is meaningful outside of that function

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use a macro to define a constant; use a constant.

```
const int thingy = 100;  // Obviously, you'll choose a better name
const int doodad = 200;

return (st.x + thingy) * st.y + doodad;
```

Like macros that expand to constant expressions, these can be treated as compile-time constants. Unlike macros, these are properly scoped within the function.

If you do have a reason for defining a macro that's only used locally, you can use `#undef` to get rid of it once you're done. But in general, you should avoid macros when (like here) there's a language-level construct that does what you want.

Comment: Furthermore, any decent compiler will optimize these to the same extent that it does literal constants; they will not occupy any additional space or time. Plus you get type checking. So there are more benefits for `const` objects over `#define` macros and no more costs.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ specifically it would be rather weird to see macros being used for that purpose. In C++ `const` completely replaces macros for defining manifest constants. And `const` works much better. (In C you'd have to stick with `#define` in many (or most) cases, but your question is tagged C++).

Having said that, pseudo-local macros sometimes come handy in C++ (especially in pre-C++11 versions of the language). If for some reason you have to `#define` such a macro "inside" a function, it is a very good idea to make an explicit `#undef` fro that macro at the end of the same scope. (I enclosed the word inside in quotes since preprocessor does not really care about scopes and can't tell "inside" from "outside".) That way you will be able to simulate the scoped visibility behavior other local identifiers have, instead of having a "locally" defined macro to spill out into the rest of the code all the way to the end of the translation unit.

Comment: thanks I didn't know there is difference in this regard between C and C++. I am working with C++ but my assumption was it would be same in both cases.

Comment: @zadane: And the surprising part is that it is *not* the same in C and C++. The treatment of `const` object and the semantics of `const` objects is significantly different between C and C++. It is actually a rather major difference between C and C++ that existed since the beginning of times. And this difference is exactly the reason why in C you have to use `#define` (or `enum`) to define named constants, while in C++ you can use a much better feature based on `const` qualifier (or, again, `enum`).